# Update status of Bing Maps or Here Maps imagery for US area?

Tags: united-states, bing-maps, here-maps, mango

Does anyone know if any updates to Bing or Here (not sure what it is now) imagery is planned for the Southeastern Washington state area?

We are not highly populated but we have a 1/4-million urban area and we are growing quickly enough that some of our new developments still look like farm fields. I think current vintage shown in our area is 2011. I saw a good answer on the state of the data in Bing/Here Maps at [BING Maps vs. HERE Maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172044/bing-maps-vs-here-maps), but not about the imagery. I ask because we use Mango Maps which defaults to Bing/Here as a basemap, and I am concerned about our web map presence looking "old" or 'dated'.

Comment: I think this is a question best asked of those vendors direct because answers here by anyone else are likely to involve a degree of speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing Maps has several large aerial imagery and road data updates planned over the next several months. Some of these have already started. US aerial imagery should be updated in the next couple of months.